# Fixing wrong 302 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302

I forgot to delete 302 flag in the following directive in htaccess, and cannot use get on the website anymore although I deleted it.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}   .

RewriteRule (.*)  /$1? [R=302,L]
```

How can I fix this? Is there a way to remove this rule?

Comment: Clear your browser cache or test in a new browser after removing this rule

Comment: @anubhava I did those. I also cleared server's (nginx) cache. None worked.

Comment: Then you have a different issue. Without the browser cache the client has to refetch the resource. If that does not work then the reason is _not_ the previous wrong redirection.